# How do I programmatically test CDN integrity in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, hash, integrity

**The Task**

I am trying to figure out how to create an hash in ASP.NET Core 2.1, which equals the hash string in the [`integrity` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) of the html `<script>` element:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**The code**

This is what I currently have:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "jQuery integrity")]
public async Task jQuery()
{
    var result = await this.Client.GetAsync("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js");
    byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    byte[] hash = SHA384.Create().ComputeHash(content);

    Assert.Equal(
        expected: "q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo",
        actual: Convert.ToBase64String(hash));
}
```

But Assert.Equals fails:

> Expected: q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smX···
>
> Actual:   w4/2hcGpax1pNE5nZ3cA34ExOY5Yr14zrL0DQdd7x···

**Question**

What exactly do I have to hash? How do I retrieve the correct hash string, so I can compare it to the one used in the HTML? Thanks in advance :)

> PS: If you ask yourselves why I want to accomplish this: Just for curiosity. I mainly wanted to check the existence of the CDN so my build process automatically throws an error if it is not available. Yes, I use the fallback feature of the `<script>` element, but this is the reason why I fear that I would not notice the absence of the CDN.

Comment: Yours is HEX and the other is base64, in case that's not obvious :P

Comment: *facepalm*. thank you @Tseng. I am going to update my question

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same code you showed us? I just copied the code and ran it and it worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that it works in my blank console application... :-/ Now I have to figure out what's the problem with my HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using a `new HttpClient()` instead of 
previously creating the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) via injecting the [`WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) into my test class and calling [`CreateClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.createclient) like recommended in the MSDN docs and Channel 9 tutorials.

However, it would by nice to know **why** those two HttpClient instances **behave differently?**